# NAV Javascript AddIn methods not working: Method 'Page90005.PageName58a58aUpdateSignature not found

Tags: javascript, navision, dynamics-nav-2016

I am trying to start with NAV Addins. I am following this tutorial:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav/2014/10/09/extensibility-for-the-microsoft-dynamics-nav-tablet-client/

I keep getting this error:

> Method 'Page90005.PageName58a58aUpdateSignature(number of arguments:
>   0), with matching argument types.' not found. (Update signature being
>   the name of the method).

and this happens with all 3 AddIn's methods.

I added the assembly file to :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\90\RoleTailored Client\Add-ins\

Everything else is the same as in the tutorial and what drives me crazy is that no one seems to have this issue.

I am trying to understand what the error is telling me (the methods are defined but not implemented or the opposite) but I can't seem to be able to solve this. 
Has anyone had a similar problem before or knows how to fix this?

I am using NAV 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After multiple tests and a lot of time spent on this issue I actually found out the whole issue came down to the name of the field that references the Control AddIn in NAV. THERE SHOULD NOT BE ANY SPACE IN THE NAME. 
I didn't expect it would have such a huge impact, I named it *Signature Control* but when I changed it to *SignatureControl* everything worked perfectly.
I hope this helps someone in the future.